# Adding an NSDictionary to an NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I've been working on this for a few days now. Searched Stackoverflow and other sites for solutions but none of them appear to work. Most of the postings I've found are quite old (before 2013) so I'm thinking this is not the right way to do this.

I thought this would work:

```
[localMutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:deviceDictionary];
```

`localMutableDictionary` remains null

I've worked around this using an array of integers instead of a mutable dictionary. But that doesn't give me the right result when I add the array to an NSDictionary for subsequent processing with NSJSONSerialisation. Values from my array don't get double quote marks around them. The json receiver / parser is expecting values in quotes (runs with json produced in VB code for a similar app). I can use an alternative parser to work around this, but I would rather get a clean solution.

This is probably a case of there being a simple syntax that I haven't managed to find, or that I'm just using an out-of-date style. Or I may just be adding my array to the NSDictionary "the wrong way". A solution for either method would work for me - thank you.

Comment: are you initialising your mutable dictionary? ie. localMutableDictionay = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; ?

Comment: No I wasn't - problem solved thank you - I've only be into Objective C for a couple of weeks. Recommend me a book on a beginners guide to Object Orientated Programming please ... then I can stop asking dumb questions.

Comment: As a side note when asking a question on SO make sure to actually ask the question because there is no question here.